# CKAN load test data - permission denied for _table_metadata

Tags: python, ckan

I installed CKAN 2.2 from source given the instructions at http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html. I also installed the datapusher service. Of what I can see it works ... I can click and browse CKAN. However, when I try to load some test data I get the error

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) permission denied for relation _table_metadata 'SECLT 1 FROM "_table_metadata" WHERE name = %s AND alias_of IS NULL' (u' ',)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, it may be that your DataStore database permissions are not set correctly, see http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#set-permissions

Comment: Yeah, I cleaned test data with paster db clean ... and forgot to db init afterwards. Your link describes everything I missed.