# CKAN DataStore - permission denied for _table_metadata

Tags: python, ckan

I I have installed and configured DataStore extension in CKAN following the guided [instructions](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#setting-up-the-datastore) but I am getting the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) permission denied for relation _table_metadata 'SELECT 1 FROM "_table_metadata" WHERE name = %s AND alias_of IS NULL'

I am a bit stuck in this moment and I don't know what else I can do for getting work DataStore. I realised that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22449566/3172792) refers more or less at the same problem as I have but the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453848/3172792) proposed doesn't work for me.

I have installed the last version of CKAN: "ckan_version": "2.4.1"

I would appreciate any help. Any advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something went wrong in this step:

```
sudo ckan datastore set-permissions | sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

When it works, it should show a few lines on the console just saying "GRANT" and "REVOKE". If however you get full SQL lines of commands then the pipe isn't working and instead you have to open psql:

```
sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

and then paste in all the commands that you saw in the console (you can paste them all in one go).

Comment: Thank you for your response but it doesn't work. If I didn't minsuderstood anything I did the following: 1) `sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1.` 2) `GRANT` and `REVOKE` that appeared to me on `paster --plugin=ckan datastore set-permissions -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini` command. And nothing has changed. Any other advice about what can I do? I forgot to say that I did the source CKAN installation.

Comment: GRANT and REVOKE suggest it is working fine - I've edited to add that to my response. In which case, I've not got any more ideas of what might have gone wrong and suggest you use a debugger.